# Blood bonded through human victim

Tags: world-of-darkness, vampire-the-masquerade

Consider a vampire draining blood from a human victim (she is hunting, for instance). If the human had previously received enough blood from another vampire (the human does not have to be a ghoul — suppose it received blood for the very first time, perhaps even injected/transfused blood), will the vampire draining the human become blood bonded to the other vampire?

I mean, could this "indirect sip" be considered as the first sip in the blood bond?

I am mostly interested in information regarding the Revised edition.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### Depends

The wording in that section of the rulebook (3rd Edition p218):

> Each sip of a particular Kindred's blood ... If a being drinks three times, on three separate nights, from the same Kindred, ...

It's vague at best. So we could say:

- No, because strictly speaking it needs to come from the Kindred directly.
- Yes, because it's an inherent power of Kindred blood.

The biggest problem resolves around: how long is Kindred blood in a human considered Kindred blood? Checking Ghouls - Fatal Addiction we come up with no further info, except for:

> One vitae is ingested, it passes very quickly (like alcohol) into the circulatory system. Plasma and all, it saturates the interior walls of the digestive tract and quickly finds its way into the veins, back to the heart, and from there throughout the body...

This seems to indicate that the Kindred blood is quickly absorbed into the human, transforming him into a Ghoul (and empowering it). Which strengthens the No case.

---

The one thing to consider is the concept of Overdosing. If a ghoul is fed Kindred blood on a nightly basis for a month, his human blood will be replaced with Kindred vitae. Feeding from such a ghoul would definitely trigger the Blood Bond.

---

In reaction to SPavel (tried to answer in comments, but it got too long):

- I doubt Kindred would feel comfortable that one of his Ghouls drinks blood from other Kindred on a daily basis.
- If this is an Independant Ghoul (Regnant is dead or he was abandoned), then following this feeding pattern would mark him as an excellent target for a Blood Hunt.
- With regards to becoming Blood Bond to the supplying Kindred: have a list of names and a d10 ready (technically it would be 10 + Stamina score of the Ghoul, but let's keep it practical). Assuming the ghoul never drinks twice from the Kindred, he will be now have a first step Blood Bond with a random Kindred (assuming that Kindred is alive; there is this rumor that the dead of the Kindred breaks all blood bonds...).

Comment: What if a ghoul drinks the blood of a different Kindred each day?

Comment: I remmember the first and second edition of Vampire had this sample adventure where Annabelle Triabelle will offer you a blood exchange (or something like that, it's been a while) and one of the dangers was to be blood bonded to their Sire, or something. Could someone double check this reference?

Comment: @Random: The scene you're thinking of is probably the one on page 248 of V:tM first edition, with Allicia. It says, "However, as she is already Bonded to Modius, the character is one step closer to coming under the control of the Prince". I don't *think* this is intended to mean bonded to the Prince, or that Modius also being Allicia's sire has much to do with it. Just that if the character does become bonded to Allicia, and Modius were to discover it, then he could use his bond to get Allicia to influence the character. Annabelle's sire is dead (consumed by Helena)

Comment: Thanks! Awesome checking :) I think my group always misunderstood this, and because we started playing with this adventure, we ended up thinking the other way around. Nice to know it is not the case (although maybe a little bit late for some stories and characters hehe!).